# Rails dynamic array to table formatting issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dynamic-arrays

I am pulling a livestream of data and trying to format it as a table. I [saw this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16328856/rails-array-to-html-table) but I am having an odd issue. The table formatting `["</td>\n\t\t</tr>\n", "</td>\n\t\t</tr>\n",.......` shows up at the top of the page, above the table itself (which is correctly formatted). Can someone explain why this is?

```
<h1>Controller1#index</h1>

graphic started<br>

<%= line_chart( [1,2,3,4,5] ) %>

<br>graphic done

<%
term="google"

client = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
  config.consumer_key        = "bi5rmrxr"
  config.consumer_secret     = "GVflzHe72OZp"
  config.access_token        = "263-SYURzb"
  config.access_token_secret = "Spc9"
end
%>
<table class="table table-condensed">
    <thead>
        <td>screen name</td> <td>time created</td><td>times favorited</td><td>text</td>
    </thead>
<%= client.search("#{term} -rt", lang: "en").take(100).collect do |tweet| %>
        <tr>
        <td><%= "#{tweet.user.screen_name}"%></td>
        <td><%= "#{tweet.created_at}"%></td>
        <td><%= "#{tweet.favorite_count}"%></td>
        <td><%= "#{tweet.text}"%></td>
        </tr>
    <% end %>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are printing client complete search as well which is being displayed at the top. you should not do not do. replace this

```
 <%= client.search("#{term} -rt", lang: "en").take(100).collect do |tweet| %>
```

with this

```
<% client.search("#{term} -rt", lang: "en").take(100).collect do |tweet| %>
```

Comment: So you are saying that `<%= xxxx %>` evaluates the expression and returns the all of the contents (including html) while `<% xxx %>` only prints the xxx to the screen?

Comment: When you use <%= it will display whatever is inside. <% is used for traversing things or the logic you are using which you don't want to print in views.